# VScode debugger for Chrome stops on random breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, angular5

So, I'm using Visual Studio Code debugger for Chrome, with Angular 5, and couple of months ago it just stopped working properly, and I cannot figure why. When I open the DevTools in Chrome, it  shows it stops on random breakpoints in the beginning of the plugin files(screenshots below). This happens only on app start and login/authorization.
My launch.json file seems fine.
Does anyone know the issue?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLP21.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgJR5.png)